# How can I select data from two tables with same structure but not related? MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to MySQL and I'm working in a project where I have two tables (TABLE A and TABLE B), both tables have the same structure, same column names, etc but they are use for different tasks.

But in some part of code is required to show info about the two tables and I think that if they have the same structure and column names why not use the same query to display the info?

I read something about `INNER JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN` but not sure if they are only to related table by foreign keys

I would like to know too if is possible to have two queries like:

`SELECT * FROM table_A..`

`SELECT * FROM table_B..`

and then combine the results in the function like `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Can you give me ideas how to achieve this or what to use? thanks.

Comment: In this case you can use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. But you shouldn't have two tables with the same structure. Consider to redesign your database.

Comment: Hi @PaulSpiegel can you tell me why? please, I mean if their tasks are differents, thanks.

Comment: If their tasks are different, then why do you want to merge them in a single query? What are the real table names?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel because is required for a pdf report generaterd with PHP, is the only part where they will merge, `tbl_info_cars` and `tbl_report_cars`

Comment: In this case (report table) it might be a valid design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [MySQL UNION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

```
(SELECT * FROM table_A) UNION (SELECT * FROM table_B)
```